# Calculating if a number is prime - why can the boolean conditional be i*i <= number?

Tags: java, conditional-statements

```
int isPrime(int number)
{

    int i;
    for(i=2; i*i <= number; i++)
    {
        if (number % i == 0)
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }

   return 1;
}
```

Why is it the case that the boolean conditional of the control statement is: i*i <= number?

Deep mathematical explanation please!

Comment: This has nothing to do with programming, really - it's just basic maths. If a number `z` has one factor `x` greater than its square root, then there must be another factor `y` such that `x * y = z`... and `y` must be *less* than the square root of `z`. So you'd already have detected `y` earlier in the algorithm.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes

Comment: For style: you should return a boolean for a `isSomething()` method.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about basic math logic.

Comment: I personally think this is a computer programming question - math and computer science are intertwined in virtue of their natures! As a computer programmer, you might want to know how to program the bounds of a for-loop (which is exactly what I am asking here). I know it seems like a pure math question, but it is only because I skipped right into the question without giving the full computer programming context!

Answer (score 3):

If a number is *not* prime then it can be written in the form `p * q`. Without loss of generality we can say that `p` cannot be greater than `q` (since we can always write the multiplication this way round).

Therefore, in checking for primality, you only need to check the `p`s since the `q`s will be implicitly checked.

So `p` going no higher than `q` is the limit. Hence `p` * `p`.

(By the way, iterating over *all* the numbers (`i++`) is also inefficient - you only need to consider primes. Choosing the appropriate algorithm really depends on your use case and without further details I can't comment further.).

Comment: I don't understand :(

Here is a counterexample:
16 (a non-prime number) can be written as 4*4 
and p = 4, and q = 4,

but p==q (and not p <= q, you said that p cannot be greater than q)

Comment: No that is not correct. If p == q then p <= q too. p is not greater than q.

Comment: Because I've disallowed that in my argument. (Which is logically valid.) Note the phrase "since we can always write the multiplication this way round".

Answer (score 2):

When not a prime, one of the factors is always <= sqrt(n), (if the potential factor is > sqrt(n), it will already have been found using the loop), so

```
i <= sqrt(n)
```

If you square both sides of the inequality:

```
i*i <= n
```

No solutions will be found outside this constraint.

Comment: You lost me at the <=sqrt part, it's really hard for me to understand why it will have been already found using the loop

Comment: numbers > sqrt(n) can't be solutions. For any factors i * j = n, if i > sqrt(n) then j < sqrt(n), so you would already have found i when the loop reached j

Answer (score 0):

Even better, you can start of at i = 3 and increase i by 2 every iteration!

```
if (number % 2 == 0) return 0;
for(i=3; i*i <= number; i+=2)
{
    if (number % i == 0)
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```